# Cambiar color de un TPanel creado en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: delphi, timer

Tengo una aplicación VCL en la que en tiempo de ejecución creo varios paneles (TPanel) dentro de un TScrolbox. Hasta ahí todo bien. A cada panel le asigné una posición dentro del Scrollbox y todos tienen un nombre (panel1, panel2, panel3, ... etc).

```
    repeat
          panel := Tpanel.Create(Scrollbox1);
          panel.Parent := Scrollbox1;
          panel.Left := nPosX + 1;
          panel.Top:= nPosY + 1;
          panel.Name := 'panel'+ inttostr(x);
          panel.Width := 100;
          panel.Height := 150;
          x := x +1;
    until(x>10);
```

También en el formulario agregué (en tiempo de diseño) un TTimer para que cada 30 segundos haga que cambie el color de alguno de los paneles

Lo que no se hacer es como debo programar en el evento OnTimer para hacer referencia a alguno de los paneles creados en tiempo de ejecución
Si escribo:

```
panel1.Color := clRed;
```

no compila porque el objeto panel1 no existe aún.

Seguramente mi pregunta es muy básica, pero bueno... soy novato en esto de crear objeto en tiempo de ejecución.

Gracias a quien pueda darme algo de información al respecto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que el Objeto `panel1` no existe en el momento de compilar el proyecto, porque como tú bien has dicho, lo has creado en tiempo de ejecución. Así que es normal que al compilación obtengas un error, ya que en ese instante aun no se ha creado.

Cuando estás ejecutando puedes acceder a cualquier componente existente utilizando su nombre. Para ello existe la función `FindComponent`. Que te devuelve una referencia al componente a partir de su nombre (que se le pasa como parámetro).

Puedes utilizarla de la siguiente manera:

```
  // Buscamoos el componente y luego hacemos un CAST
  TPanel(FindComponent('panel1')).Color := clBlue;
```

Si el componente no se encuentra o no es un `TPanel` te devolverá un `Access Violation`, así que no está de más realizar algunas comprobaciones.
Aquí tienes otro código para esa función que además evita los errores más comunes:

```
var
  c:TComponent;
begin
  // Buscamos el componente a partir de su nombre
  c := FindComponent('panel1');
  // Si no ha encontrado estará asignado, sino tendremos un NIL
  if Assigned(c) then begin
    // Comprobamos que realmente es un TPanel (y no de otra clase)
    if (c is TPanel) then begin
      // Finalmente hacemos el CAST y cambiamos el color
      TPanel(c).Color := clGreen;
    end;
  end;
```

En este caso, se comprueba que hemos encontrado el componente y que realmente es de la clase correcta antes de realizar el `CAST`.

**OPTIMIZACIÓN:**
`FindComponent` no es una de las funciones más eficientes, ya que recorre **TODOS** los componentes para buscar el que necesitas de forma secuencial. Si tienes muchos componentes o la vas a utilizar muchas veces, lo recomendable sería optimizar este proceso.

Por ejemplo, podrías crear un `TObjectList` (lista de referencias) e ir añadiendo los `TPanel` que creas. De esta forma mantendrás una lista de apuntadores a los componentes creados.
Para acceder a los `TPanel` en ejecución, sólo deberás acceder a los componentes a partir de la lista (así evitar recorrer cada vez secuencialmente todos los componentes).

Defines la lista como (parte privada del formulario/clase):

```
  oList:TObjectList;
```

La creas así:

```
  oList := TObjectList.Create;
```

Añades los paneles creados así:

```
  panel := Tpanel.Create(Scrollbox1);
  panel.Parent := Scrollbox1;
  panel.Left := nPosX + 1;
  panel.Top:= nPosY + 1;
  panel.Name := 'panel'+ inttostr(x);
  // Añadir el objeto à la lista
  oList.Add(panel);
```

Y para acceder a ellos lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera. Si los has añadido en orden, puedes acceder a través del índice. El 0 será el `panel1`, el 1 el `panel2`,...

```
var
  p:TPanel;
begin
  p := TPanel(oList[1]).Color := clGreen;
```